# rspec shared_context and include_context for all specs

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to define a few `let`'s and `before` hooks that will run globally for all my specs by including them in a separate file using the [Rspec configuration block](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration).

I tried something like:

```
module Helpers
  def self.included(base)
    base.let(:x){ "x" }
    base.before(:all){ puts "x: #{x}" }
  end
end

Rspec.configure{|c| c.include Helpers }
```

but this doesn't work as expected.  The `before(:all)` doesn't just run before each main example group, but each nested one as well.

Then I found out about [shared_context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context) and it appears to be exactly what I want.

My open problem however is that I can't figure out how to share a context amongst *ALL* of my specs.  The docs only reference `include_context` within a specific spec.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this behavior in a global manner?  I'm aware that I can define global before hooks in my `spec_helper` but I can't seem to use `let`.  I'd like a single place that I can define both of these things and not pollute my spec helper, but just include it instead.

Comment: According to RSpec tests, `before(:all)` must [run only once](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-8/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#7), no matter where it was defined. So maybe its an RSpec issue?

Comment: no i don't think this is an rspec issue.  I don't think the above code is the intended usage of including modules in the config.  I'm pretty sure that module will get included in every example group, including nested ones, so it makes sense that my `before(:all)` runs before each example group.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce your error, but failed.

```
# spec_helper.rb
require 'support/global_helpers'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MyApp::GlobalHelpers
end

# support/global_helpers.rb
module MyApp
  module GlobalHelpers
    def self.included(base)
      base.let(:beer) { :good }
      base.before(:all) { @bottles = 10 }
    end
  end  
end

# beer_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Brewery" do

  it "makes good stuff" do
    beer.should be :good
  end

  it "makes not too much bottles" do
    @bottles.should == 10
  end

  context "when tasting beer" do
    before(:all) do
      @bottles -= 1
    end

    it "still produces good stuff" do
      beer.should be :good
    end

    it "spends some beer on degusting" do
      @bottles.should == 9
    end   
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/2283634

When I wrote something like `base.before(:all) { p 'global before'; @bottles = 10 }`, I got exactly one line in spec output.

Notice that I didn't try to modify instance variables inside an example, because [it wouldn't work anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752128/issue-with-instance-variable-and-rspec-2-x) (well, actually you *can* modify instance variables, if it's a hash or array). Moreover, even if you change `before(:all)` in nested example group to `before(:each)`, there will be still 9 bottles in each example.

Comment: oh interesting... i was using an old version of rspec, new version only runs once... maybe I *can* do what I want!

Comment: there's something still weird going on.  I have a `before(:all)` that *just* does a `puts` statement, and it breaks my tests in unexplainable ways.  Take out that `before(:all)` and it all works.  I still don't think using a module like that is the intended method.  I'm pretty sure I want a `shared_context`, just don't know how to use it globally.