# Automatically share context in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to share a memoized method between my specs. So I tried to use shared context like this

```
RSpec.configure do |spec|
  spec.shared_context :specs do
    let(:response) { request.execute! }
  end
end

describe 'something' do
  include_context :specs
end
```

It works ok. But I have about 60 spec files, so I'm forced to explicitly include context in each of them. Is there an way to automatically include shared context (or at least `let` definition) for all example groups in `spec_helper.rb`?

Something like this

```
RSpec.configure do |spec|
  spec.include_context :specs
end
```

Comment: This probably duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965111/rspec-shared-context-and-include-context-for-all-specs but it still doesn't have answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set up global `before` hooks using `RSpec.configure` via [configure-class-methods](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec#configure-class_method) and [Configuration](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration):

```
RSpec.configure {|c| c.before(:all) { do_stuff }}
```

`let` is not supported in `RSpec.configure`, but you *can* set up a global `let` by including it in a [SharedContext module](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/SharedContext) and including that module using `config.before`:

```
module MyLetDeclarations
  extend RSpec::Core::SharedContext
  let(:foo) { Foo.new }
end
RSpec.configure { |c| c.include MyLetDeclarations }
```

Comment: FYI for anyone using RSpec 3, it looks like `RSpec::Core::SharedContext` has gone away, and been replaced with `RSpec::SharedContext`.

Comment: This is a nice solution. A small gotcha that I came across in RSpec 3 is that when passing a tag to include and having that tag on my example blocks (rather than example group blocks) I got an error `NoMethodError: super: no superclass method \`foo' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::...> Did you mean? #foo`. The fix is just to make sure the tag is on the example group rather than the example.

Comment: I hit the same error as @GabeKopley but I found that upgrading to RSpec 3.4.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

In RSpec 3+, this can be achieved as follows - based on Jeremy Peterson's answer.

```
# spec/supprt/users.rb
module SpecUsers
  extend RSpec::SharedContext

  let(:admin_user) do
    create(:user, email: 'admin@example.org')
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SpecUsers
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it *almost* like that: there's a mechanism for including a module, and module inclusion has its own callback mechanism.

Suppose for example that we have a `disconnected` shared context that we want to use to run all our model specs without a database connection.

```rb
shared_context "disconnected"  do
  before :all do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: :nulldb)
  end

  after :all do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:test)
  end
end
```

You can now create a module that will include that context on inclusion.

```rb
module Disconnected
  def self.included(scope)
    scope.include_context "disconnected"
  end
end
```

Finally, you can include that module into all specs in the normal manner (I've demonstrated doing it only for models, just to show that you can), which is almost exactly what you asked for.

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Disconnected, type: :model
end
```

That works with `rspec-core` 2.13.0 and `rspec-rails` 2.13.0.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go is to [automatically share examples via metadata](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context#declare-a-shared-context-and-include-it-with-metadata). So:

```
shared_context 'a shared context', a: :b do
  let(:foo) { 'bar' }
end

describe 'an example group', a: :b do
  # I have access to 'foo' variable
end
```

The most common way I use it is in rspec-rails, with some shared context depending on the example group type. So if you have `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!`, you can simply do:

```
shared_context 'a shared context', type: :controller do
  let(:foo) { 'bar' }
end

describe SomeController do
  # I have access to 'foo' variable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you need ability to use shared data in `before` blocks inside specs, as me, try to include this (if its Rails project):

```
module SettingsHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_reader :default_headers

    before :all do
      @default_headers = Hash[
          'HTTP_HOST' => 'test.lvh.me'
        ]
    end

    after :all do
      @default_headers = nil
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include SettingsHelper
end
```

Or try something similar, look at @threedaymonk answer.